# Struggling to Apply "Differences"

Tags: list-manipulation, code-request

It looks like the following code should work, and allow it spits out error messages saying I have too many arguments, the code spit out after the error message looks like exactly what I want to calculate, but it won't give the answers. Completely stumped here...

```
list[b_, c_] := Table[{a, b, c}, {a, 0, c - 1}];
list2 = Tuples[Table[list[Prime[8], c], {c, 5, 7}]];

list3[a_, b_, c_] := Union[
  Range[a, b, Prime[c]],
  Range[a + 2, b, Prime[c]]]

list4 = Union @@@ Apply[list3, list2, {2}];
Apply[Differences, list4, 1]
```

Here's the output:

```
{Differences[0, 2, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19], 
 Differences[0, 1, 2, 3, 11, 13, 15, 18], 
 Differences[0, 2, 4, 11, 13, 15, 19], 
 Differences[0, 2, 3, 5, 11, 13, 15], 
 Differences[0, 2, 4, 6, 11, 13, 15], 
 Differences[0, 2, 5, 7, 11, 13, 15],...
```

Those are the differences I want. How do I get it to spit them out?

Comment: Why are you applying? This should be mapped...

Comment: @ciao Sorry, I'm new. What do you mean?

Comment: `Map[Differences, list4]` or just `Differences/@list4`

Comment: @ciao That did it! Would you post as an answer with an explanation of the difference :-) between apply and map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to *Map* here, not *Apply*:

`Map[Differences, list4]` or just `Differences/@list4`

`Map` takes the sub-lists of list4 as the argument to `Differences` for each, `Apply`*replaces the heads* (`List`) on the sub-lists with `Differences` (so the elements of the list all become arguments to `Differences`), hence the error message: `Differences` expects a list (and optional remaining arguments up to 3 total arguments), but you are feeding it the list elements themselves.

The error message tells you this.